# Setting timeout for AngularJS $watch function

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to add a timeout to an AngularJS $watch function?

For example, let's say I have the below AngularJS code that's watching a value, *myName*. When the value changes, the listener function runs. But if the value does not change within a certain period of time, I want it to do something else.

Specifically, in the code below, I would want $scope.nothingEnteredFlag to change from false to true. My html template be set up to reflect the state of that flag (e.g., using ng-show).

```
var app = angular.module("helloApp", []);
app.controller("helloCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.nothingEnteredFlag=false;
    $scope.$watch("myName", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if ($scope.myName.length < 5) {
            $scope.message = "Short name!";
        } else {
            $scope.message = "Long name!";
        }
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o5tvydb/1/).

I've tried surrounding the $watch with $timeout, but can't seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular [timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to achieve your desire result.

```
var timer;
  var timerFunction = function() {
    timer = $timeout(function() {
      $scope.nothingEnteredFlag = true;
    }, 5000);
  };
```

This is will create the timer function

Your controller should like this

```
var app = angular.module("helloApp", []);
app.controller("helloCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.nothingEnteredFlag = false;
  $scope.myName = "";
  $scope.$watch("myName", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ($scope.myName.length < 5) {
      $scope.message = "Short name!";
    } else {
      $scope.message = "Long name!";
    }
    $scope.nothingEnteredFlag = false;
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
    timerFunction();
  });
  var timer;
  var timerFunction = function() {
    timer = $timeout(function() {
      $scope.nothingEnteredFlag = true;
    }, 5000);
  };
  timerFunction();
});
```

As you can see we have enabled timeout of the 5 seconds once user enters any text we cancel the timer and enable it again, this way we can prompt the user to enter if he hasn't wrote anything in five seconds.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4FuyY/97/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Works great!